# LSTM neural network for a chemical process?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I have the following dataset[image: dataset]
for a chemical process in a refinery. It's comprised of 5x5 input vector where each vector is sampled at every minute. The output is the result of the whole process and sampled each 5 minutes.

I concluded that the output (yellow) depends highly on past input vectors in a timely manner. And got recently to have a look on LSTMs and trying to learn a bit about them on Python and Torch.

However I don't have any idea how should I prepare my dataset in a manner where my LSTM could process it and show me future predictions if tested with new input vectors.

Is there a straight forward manner to preprocess my dataset accordingly?

EDIT1: Actually i found out this awesome blog about training LSTMs on natural language processing http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/ . Long story short, an LSTM takes a character as an input and tries to generate the next character. Eventually, it can be trained on Shakespeare poems to generate new Shakespeare poems! But GPU acceleration is recommended.

EDIT2: Based on EDIT1, the best way to format my dataset is to just transform my excel to txt with TAB-separated columns. I'll post the results of the LSTM prediction on my above numbers dataset as soon as possible.